# Swift: How to pass array items in tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode6, tableview

I'm trying to pass array values to a tableview.
@ //4 `println(items)` it prints an array with values to my console. I want to have those results passed in to the tableview. The tableview is working but gets it's value from `var list: [String] = ...`

How do I get the `println(items)` in the `var list: [String] = ...` ?

Thanks!!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var list: [String] = ["Row One", "Row Two", "Row Three" , "Row Four", "Row Five"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        var results = "today"
        var subItem = "movie"
        
        // hier moet de opegslagen bioscoop komen die door de gebruiker is opgeslagen als keuze
        var cinemaFilter = "Pathé Arena"
        
        // Get the Cinema's from scraper and SwiftyJSON
        DataManager.getCinemaDataFromScraperWithSuccess { (ScraperData) -> Void in
            let json = JSON(data: ScraperData)
            if let itemName = json["results"][results][0][subItem]["text"].stringValue {
                println("Film resultaten:")
            }
            //1
            if let itemArray = json["results"][results].arrayValue {
                //2
                var items = [itemModel]()
                
                //3
                for itemDict in itemArray {
                    var itemName: String? = itemDict[subItem]["text"].stringValue
                    var itemTime: String? = itemDict["time"]["text"].stringValue
                    var itemCinema: String? = itemDict["cinema"]["text"].stringValue
                    
                    if itemCinema == cinemaFilter {
                        var item = itemModel(name: itemName, time: itemTime, cinema: itemCinema )
                        items.append(item)
                    } else {
                        //println("is niet de ingestelde bioscoop")
                    }
                    
                }
                
                //4
                println(items)
            }
        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.list.count;
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.list[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. You're fiddling with some `itemArray` but your table view takes data from `list`

Comment: I want the itemArray data in the tableview. The tableview gets it's data from the list so i figured i need to pass the itemsArray items in to the list somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Make `items` an instance variable of your view controller instead of a local variable, use it in the data source methods, and get rid of `list`.

You then need to decide what part of an `item` you want to show in `cell.textLabel?.text`, name, time, cinema, or some combination.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var items = [itemModel]()` inside the func place it on class lavel so it's an instance. Then change

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}
```

and the cell method accordingly to use items.